# Selecting a Shopify variant for a gift card doesn't trigger necessary change to update payment button

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am trying to get users to select a variant before enabling the "add to cart" button, which works exactly as intended on normal product pages. However with the gift card this is not happening properly and I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

When I go to the highlighted portion of the code something seems to go wrong here, specifically at the `dispatchEvent` part:

```
_onSelectChange: function() {
    var variant = this._getVariantFromOptions();

    this.container.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('variantChange', {
            detail: {
                variant: variant
              },
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
            })
        );

    if (!variant) {
      return;
    }

    this._updateMasterSelect(variant);
    this._updateImages(variant);
    this._updatePrice(variant);
    this._updateSKU(variant);
    this.currentVariant = variant;
    this._updatePaymentButton(variant);

    if (this.enableHistoryState) {
        this._updateHistoryState(variant);
    }
}
```

The URL changes to the correct variant and console logging the variant also gives me the correct information. The add to cart button doesn't enable itself like it does on a normal product page, so i had to manually enable it using JavaScript. When clicking the enabled button it just loads infinitely, instead of showing the cart popup. The product however is added to the cart so as a temporary fix on the gift card page i set the `location.href` to the cart page after clicking the button, but ideally the customers would remain on the same page and get a popup that says the product has been added to the cart.

If someone could help me out that would be amazing since the Shopify forum is no help at all.

Comment: Do you have a URL to the Shopify site ? Or can you share the name of the theme if you are using some default Shopify theme ? Difficult to tell without looking at `_getVariantFromOptions` function